# Combining commands in shell works but doesn't work in when running a .sh file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, jobs

When I run these command on the unix shell interactively, I get to log the outputs in `jobs-ran-before-lunch`

```
alvas@turing:~$ date >> jobs-ran-before-lunch && jobs -l >> jobs-ran-before-lunch
alvas@turing:~$ cat jobs-ran-before-lunch 
Fri Oct  2 11:44:41 UTC 2015
[4]   8765 Running                 nohup bash do-something.sh &  (wd: ~/wmt-data)
[5]   8786 Running                 nohup bash do-something.sh &  (wd: ~/wmt-data)
[7]   8926 Running                 nohup bash do-something.sh &  (wd: ~/wmt-data)
[8]-  8946 Running                 nohup bash do-something.sh &  (wd: ~/wmt-data)
```

But when I save the command:

```
date >> jobs-ran-before-lunch && jobs -l >> jobs-ran-before-lunch
```

in a `.sh` script file (`logjobs.sh`), it did not run jobs and append to the `jobs-ran-before-lunch` file:

```
alvas@turing:~$ echo 'date >> jobs-ran-before-lunch && jobs -l >> jobs-ran-before-lunch' > logjobs.sh 
alvas@turing:~$ bash logjobs.sh 
alvas@turing:~$ cat jobs-ran-before-lunch 
Fri Oct  2 11:44:41 UTC 2015
[4]   8765 Running                 nohup bash do-something.sh &  (wd: ~/wmt-data)
[5]   8786 Running                 nohup bash do-something.sh &  (wd: ~/wmt-data)
[7]   8926 Running                 nohup bash do-something.sh &  (wd: ~/wmt-data)
[8]-  8946 Running                 nohup bash do-something.sh &  (wd: ~/wmt-data)
Fri Oct  2 11:44:56 UTC 2015
```

**Why is that so? And how do I make sure that my commands in `logjobs.sh` work such that I get to log the output of `jobs -l` in `jobs-ran-before-lunch`?**

Comment: source your script `. logjobs.sh` instead of executing it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running it as a new script it has its own process and jobs, not those of the calling process.  So it is, in fact, showing you all the jobs that the script has.

If you want to execute it in your calling context, not the context of the newly executed script you can do as gniourf_gniourf says and source the file instead.